# Mysql metastore database is not reflected in Hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have configured mysql as the metastore in Hive.

I created a database called as ITAG in mysql but the same database is not reflected in hive.

**Output of mysql**

```
mysql> show databases;

+--------------------+

| Database           |

+--------------------+

| information_schema |

| ITAGDB             |

| OOZIE              |

| madmart_db         |

| mysql              |

| performance_schema |

| qreda_global       |

| sys                |

+--------------------+


8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Output of hive**

```
hive> show databases;

OK

default

test
```

**Problem** - ITAGDB database residing in mysql is not reflected in hive. Kindly help

Comment: Why should it? When you run `CREATE DATABASE` in Hive, it just adds an entry in a specific table in your _ITAGDB_ MySQL database (and also manages the storage area as an HDFS dir).

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I got the below given error while creating a table

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter  Error in metadata: javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Insert of object "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MStorageDescriptor@1fdca564" using statement "INSERT INTO `SDS` (`SD_ID`,`NUM_BUCKETS`,`SERDE_ID`,`LOCATION`,`INPUT_FORMAT`,`IS_COMPRESSED`,`CD_ID`,`OUTPUT_FORMAT`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" failed : Field 'IS_STOREDASSUBDIRECTORIES' doesn't have a default value

Comment: So your Metastore DB schema was not created properly, or you are using a version of Metastore service that does not match the version of the schema... But anyway this issue is different from your original post.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter M using hive version 0.9.0. How to check the metastore version. Any suggestion from your end ?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Could you help me out in finding the schema for hive 0.9.0. Iam new to hadoop. Please help

Comment: Hive 0.9 has been obsolete for **years**. If you don't know anything about that hugely complex stack that is the Hadoop ecosystem, then at least, try to use a pre-packaged distro w/ an install wizard, or download a sandbox!

Comment: You would query the **metastore database** table in Mysql, to find the version. Unclear which one that is, but Hive only shares a single database with Mysql, and none others. Please edit your question to include how you managed to "configured mysql as the metastore in Hive" because I'm fairly sure Hive 0.9 isn't even available for downloading anymore, and it does not appear you've ran any `initSchema` command from Hive to setup a metastore